# Добавление в multimap

Tags: c++

Есть

```
multimap<pair<wstring, wstring>, wstring>.
```

Не получается так добавить элемент:

```
elementsList.emplace((stream.str(), file), elementPath);
```

Как должно быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, как минимум, можно так:

```
elementsList.emplace(make_pair(stream.str(),file),elementPath);
```

Поскольку для `pair` нет `emplace`, вряд ли что-то лучшее можно сделать...

Comment: Спасибо попробую.

Comment: `Поскольку для pair нет emplace` - что Вы хотели этим сказать?

Comment: Ну, я подумал, что если бы была функция-член `emplace` или ее аналог для `pair`, можно было бы надеяться, что `emplace` для `multimap` вызвало бы ее для указанных аргументов? Или можно было бы вызвать прямо ее для размещения вместо создания объекта?